# How to decompile python .exe who compiled by Nuitka?

Tags: python, decryption, encryption, unpacking, crackme

i have one file named hello.exe and compiled using nuitka by cmd :

*python -m nuitka --mingw64 --windows-icon-from-ico=ICON.ico --onefile --windows-company-name=NAME --windows-product-version=1.0 --plugin-enable=tk-inter pyfilehere*

and i have no idea how to reverse that, did u guys know ?

Comment: A good starting point would be the source code and documentation of Nuitka: https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka